# How to http post two different json objects in single entity?

Tags: android, json, rest, http-post

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Creating HTTP Post
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("www.somewebsite.com");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(getJSONString(), "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Making HTTP Request
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

This works fine for me. However I want to send other `jsonobject` with business data to server. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just merge the 2 **JSONObjects** into 1.

```
{   
 "json_1": {
    "a": "1"   
 },   
 "json_2": {
    "b": "2"   
 } 
}
```

Comment: Will server understands the strings "json_1" and "json_2"? Here, first jsonobject is for server authentication(contains id and regn key) and the second jsonobject is to send business data.

Comment: That your back-end has to take care, something like: getTheWholeJSONObject jObj; 1_jsonobject = jObj.getJSONObject("json_1"); 2_jsonobject = jObj.getJSONObject("json_2");

Comment: Yeah got it! But I don't have control over server. Anyways I have created two httpPosts and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can only send one entity, so your function `getJSONString()` will need to be updated to return both objects as one string.

You might want to consider sending a proper JSON list.

```
[
    { /* object one */ },
    { /* object two */ }
]
```

I think this is much more preferable over a 'combined object'

```
{
    "object one" : { /* object one */ },
    "object two" : { /* object two */ }
}
```

Using a combined object makes it awkward to parse, as you have to explicitly get each sub object out of the main object. With the array, you can simply loop through each element of the list, which means adding more to the list is as easy as adding more to the list. Your exact usage may mean that the combined object is better, such as if you need to know the exact order the sub-objects should be handled; JSON lists are unordered you see.

Comment: What is "object one" and "object two" here? Can I name anything so that server understands?

Comment: yeah, it's json. Those are the keys you would use to get the corresponding objects back. I suggest you take a quick look at [json.org](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score -1):

Simple! Club both json's using a separator, and then delimit using the separator on the server.

Or build a new json object with both jsons' and send a common json object to the server.

Nithin